Объединить в один контур


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="29.5" height="36" viewBox="0 0 170 36">
    <path d="M150.805 17.91a63.558 71.067 0 0 1-63.558 71.067A63.558 71.067 0 0 1 23.689 17.91a63.558 71.067 0 0 1 63.558-71.067 63.558 71.067 0 0 1 63.558 71.067Z" style="opacity:.79;fill:red;stroke-width:5.76271"/>
    <path d="M124.79 16.747a36.908 36.274 0 0 1-36.908 36.274 36.908 36.274 0 0 1-36.908-36.274 36.908 36.274 0 0 1 36.908-36.274 36.908 36.274 0 0 1 36.908 36.274Z" style="opacity:.79;fill:red;stroke-width:5.76271"/>
</svg>



Как объединить, ясно. Вопрос в другом.
Когда объединяем в один объект. Как в Inkscape, сделать так, чтобы малый круг был белым?
При условии что холст прозрачный... И на выходе получить один path

Чтобы малый круг стал дыркой в большом? Меню "Контур" -> "Исключающее или", либо "Разность"

Тогда круг будет дыркой, прозрачным. Необходимо белым и одним patch

Один путь не получится 2 цвета (красный, белый) — 2 пути. Попробуйте второй путь поправить так style="opacity:1;fill:white;stroke-width:5.76271" Можно сделать и одним путем, тогда красное должно быть обводкой границы. <path d="M 253.277 177.408 C 253.277 197.442 236.753 213.682 216.369 213.682 C 195.985 213.682 179.461 197.442 179.461 177.408 C 179.461 157.374 195.985 141.134 216.369 141.134 C 236.753 141.134 253.277 157.374 253.277 177.408 Z" style="opacity: 1; fill: white; stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 22px;"></path>
